# Does .bashrc create a parent shell in which the current working shell are spawned

Tags: bash

When set a directory as persistent, `export` should be employed and add it to ~/.bashrc

```
PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH
```

Does this mean that my current working shell is a subshell created from a parent-shell in script ~/.bashrc

```
$ var=3; export var; bash
$ echo $var
3
```

The parent shell export the variable to subshell.

Does `~/.bashrc` work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `~/.bashrc` does not start a new shell.

The `~/.bashrc` initialization file is *sourced*, i.e. read and executed in the same environment as the shell that invoked it (not run as a script).

The shell is essentially doing `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc` to execute the contents of the file without spawning a new shell instance.

When you do `export variable=value` on the command line (or `variable=value; export variable`), you set `variable` to `value` and you mark the variable as "exported", i.e. it is turned into an environment variable that will be inherited by subsequent processes started from the same shell.  No new shell is started by `export`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in spawning a new shell and `.bashrc` is not a script, rather a text file. You can see what's going on when you monitor your shell's PID and introduce changes to your `.bashrc`. For them to take effect, just source the file:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

No new process is spawned. It's as if you typed by hand all those lines included in that file. `export` by itself doesn't require a new shell. It only changes the environment, which *can be* inherited in the future.